# Does $H^i(E) = 0$ for $i \geq 0$ imply $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{A})}(E, A) = 0$ for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category, $\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{A})$ be the derived category, and consider an object $E \in \mathbf{D}(\mathcal{A})$ with $H^i(E) = 0$ for all $i \geq 0$. Is it true that
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{A})}(E, A) = 0 \tag{$*$}$$
for all objects $A \in \mathcal{A}$ (considered as a cochain complex in degree $0$)?

I realized, that $E$ is quasi-isomorphic to the subcomplex $E' \subset E$, given by
$$\dots \to E^{-2} \to E^{-1} \to \operatorname{im}(d^{-1}) \to 0 \to \cdots,$$
and that any chain map $E' \to A$ is zero-homotopic, but [apparently that is not enough](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519585/does-operatornamehom-mathbf-k-mathcalaa-b-0-imply-operatorna) to conclude $(*)$.

This argument seems to appear in Bridgeland's *Stability conditions on K3 surfaces*, in the proof of **Lemma 10.1**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E$ is quasi-isomorphic to a complex $P$ of projectives so $$Hom_{D}(E,A) = Hom_{K}(P,A) = Hom(H^0P,A) = 0$$

See 1.49-1.51 of https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~dmattei/MemoireM2_Dominique_Mattei.pdf

Comment: So my category is $\mathcal{A} = \operatorname{Coh}(X)$ for a projective surface $X$, so I probably have to take injective resolutions. But this might still work, right?

Comment: In general If the max $i$ st $E_i\neq 0$ is $\leq$ the min $j$ st $A_j=0$ then $Hom_K(E,I) = Hom(H^iE, I^i)$ which if $H^iE =0$ is zero.

Comment: If $i>j$ on the other hand then even for objects in degree 0 you start to get Ext terms, $Hom_D(X[-i],Y[-j]) = Ext^{i-j}(X,Y)$ which may be nonzero